# Sending large XML string in ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs4

I am having a large xml string that i want to send to the server side using an ajax call.

I want to send it using ExtJs 4 Ext.Ajax.request or javascript Ajax call (NO JQUERY).

I have used escape function while sending the xmlString but I am unable to get the complete xml string on the server side.

Can some pls guide me how to send large xml string on the server side using extjs ajax request or javascript ajax request ?

Following is the line of code that i am using -

On client side i have a var named xmlString which contains svg xml as a string.

```
var xmlString="<xml>  + ........." ;
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'myUrl',
    params: {
        svgXml: xmlString
    },
    success: function(response){
    }
});
```

On server side when i get svgXml param from request, i dont get the complete xml string that i had send in the above ajax request.

Comment: Show what you have and explain what doesn't work

Comment: Does it work if you do *not* escape anything? I'm pretty sure extjs takes care of that.

Comment: What *do* you get at the server? What does your browser's Net debug tab tell you is being sent?